Is there a way to check if a list(A) contains a value from list(B), and then remove the item from list(B) if it's true?
The following is what I'm trying to achieve:

Get data from emails into a list(B)
get data from excel column into a list(A)
check to see if the any of the values match between both lists
if any of the values match, the value will be removed from the list(B)
The final list is then written to a txt file
The images added show what I've done to get it to work, but I've had no luck. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Image 1 of power automate desktop flow
Image 2 of power automate desktop flow
Image 3 of power automate desktop flow
EDIT: I have no problem with getting the data into the lists, It's just the removal of the data from the list that is not working

b.removeAll(a); And Set probably would be better than List. More complex types can still use b.removeIf(belem -> a.contains(belem.afield))

Your question is tagged both power-automate and powerapps... Are you trying to do this in an app or in a flow?

I Don't think I'm able to do this in power automate desktop, this is java syntax right?

I'm trying to achieve this in power automate desktop as a flow, I have removed the irrelevant tags. please see the images attached for reference as to what I've tried so far
